# How to add SOAP action to the webservice in java?

Tags: java, soap, action

I am working on the SOAP webservice. I have used the annotation like : @webService(endPointInterface=) , @ WebMethod ,@WebResult.

```
Code :

<wsdl:operation name="thumbNailImageService">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="thumbNailImageService">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
```

**I am getting WSDL for the above request,But my SOAP action is null(blank string).**

**I want to add SOAP action from my java code like any of the annotation.**

**Resolution needed :**

```
<soap:operation soapAction="Any Action URl points to service" style="document"/>
```

**Help me out using java code to add SOAP action using annotation.**

I am using import or library for it as below :

```
**import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Use;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;**
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With JAX-WS you can specify the `action` attribute of the `@WebMethod` annotation. It binds to the `action` attribute of the `soap:operation` tag. See the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/jws/WebMethod.html#action%28%29).